# why am i getting Cannot add foreign key constraint error when migrating tables?

Tags: laravel-migrations

Im trying to migrate my tags tables but i keep getting this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `post_tag` add constraint `post_tag_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`))

when running:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

here is my code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');
}
}
```

CreateTagsTable:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
}
}
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: Does making the type of those foreign keys unsigned big integer solve your issue? (e.g.`$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned()` instead of `$table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()`) If it does, you can also use `$table->foreignId('post_id')`.

Comment: that worked thank you.

Comment: Nice, then the reason is what I suspected. `id()` creates a column of type bigIncrement, which is an unsigned bigint that gets incremented automatically. The foreign keys referring to that column should have the correct type (unsigned bigint), which can be achieved automatically using the alias `foreignId()`.